# How to fetch 3 lines above a matched parameter

Tags: grep, aix

I want to print 3 lines above a matched parameter in a log file. I am using following command, but it gives me an error.
Is there any alternative to this.

> grep -A 3 "exception" Services.log

It gives the following error:

```
grep: Not a recognized flag: A
Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L] [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] -e pattern_list...
        [-f pattern_file...] [file...]
```

Comment: I've added the `aix` tag to your question. Let us know if you're on some other Unix than AIX.

Comment: Yes im on Aix, Sorry i forgot to mention

Comment: could you clarify whether you want 3 lines that occur before the matching line or you want 3 lines that occur after the matching line? for example, if you have 10 lines in input and matching line is 5th, you want 5,6,7,8 or 2,3,4,5?

Answer (score 2):

The following `awk` command would give you the line that contains the string `exception` along with three lines of "before context" (`-B 3` with GNU `grep` and some other `grep` implementations):

```
awk 'BEGIN { bc=3 } { lines[NR%(bc+1)] = $0 } /exception/ { for (i=1; i<=(bc+1); ++i) print lines[(NR+i)%(bc+1)] }' file
```

This keeps a "circular buffer", `lines`, of `bc+1` lines, where `bc` is the number of lines of "before context" you want.  When a line matches the pattern `exception`, the contents of this buffer is printed.

This does not properly handle the case where a match occurs *within* the "before context" of another match, or where the first match in the file occurs less than `bc` lines into the file.

Generalized into a script that gives you a configurable amount of context before and after for some pattern:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Usage:
#    ./script [ -A n ] [ -B n ] PATTERN FILE ...

after=0
before=0

while getopts 'A:B:' opt; do
    case $opt in
    A)
        after=$OPTARG
        ;;
    B)
        before=$OPTARG
        ;;
    *)
        echo 'error in command line parsing' >&2
        exit 1
    esac
done
shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

pattern=$1
shift

pattern=$pattern awk -v bc="$before" -v ac="$after" '
    { lines[NR%(bc+1)] = $0 }
    $0 ~ ENVIRON["pattern"] {
        for (i=1; i<=(bc+1); ++i) print lines[(NR+i)%(bc+1)]
        print_after=ac
        next
    }
    print_after > 0 { print; print_after-- }' "$@"
```

Testing it:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5
exception
6
7
8
9
0
exception
```

```
$ sh script.sh -B 3 exception file
3
4
5
exception
8
9
0
exception
```

```
$ sh script.sh -A 3 exception file
exception
6
7
8
exception
```

```
$ sh script.sh -A 1 -B 1 exception file
5
exception
6
0
exception
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple but not necessarily efficient:

```
tac Services.log | awk '/exception/ {L = NR + 4} NR < L' | tac
```

Comment: If they don't have GNU `grep`, then the are unlikely to have other GNU utilities, such as `tac` (part of GNU coreutils).